# Is there a way to reserve a range in a postgres sequence?

Tags: postgresql

I'm writing a program that generates large numbers of rows to be inserted into a PostgreSQL database. Due to the presence of multiple indices, this process is getting slower over time. That's why I want to move to using COPY which seems to be significantly faster. The problem is that one of the tables has a foreign key into another, and I do not have the IDs for the foreign key column.

I was thinking that maybe if I could reserve a range in the sequence used for the primary key of the first table, I could do the ID assignment manually but I don't think Postgres natively supports such an operation. Is there a way to achieve this another way?

Comment: sounds like a job for a temp table?

Comment: How so? Not sure how a temp table can help.

Comment: "Due to the presence of multiple indices, this process is getting slower over time. That's why I want to move to using COPY which seems to be significantly faster."  Indices slow down COPY as well.  Proportionally, they slow it down much more, as it starts out being so much faster.

Comment: Populate a temp table, run a query to fill in the foreign keys, then insert from the temp table into the real table.

Comment: Data is being generated for both tables on the fly. So how would that work? Populate two temp tables with data, one with foreign keys referring to the other temp table. Then, how do I copy these into the main tables? Foreign keys would somehow need to be updated again, and I can't see how. I would love to see a working solution if you could spare some time to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off from your source data identify the business key for the parent and child tables. Create those tables and a unique constraint business key. This will **not be the surrogate - auto generated - PK**. Now create a staging table with all the columns necessary (except the FK). Since you will most likely be using across sessions this is a permanent table, but the intent is single time usage. With this insert into the parent table generating the pk from the sequence. Then insert into the child selecting the FK by referencing the business key from the parent.

```
insert into parent( <columns> )  
     select column_list 
       from  stage
         on conflict (business key ) do nothing; 
          
insert into child ( <columns>, )
     select s.<columns>, a.id 
       from stage s 
       join parent a on s.business key = a.business key
       on conflict (a.parent_id, child_bk) do nothing;
```

Since the above is rather obscure in the abstract see a concrete [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=15ddc705148f957bad192a130546ad74). There is no need attempting to "reserve a range", just let the pk/fk develop naturally.

Comment: Apologies for getting back to this so late. I went on holidays and then got sidetracked by other work. This looks like a viable solution and I think I can make it work with what I'm about to attempt, so I'll mark it as accepted even though I haven't tried it yet.